# Is there any way to not have to specify an array size before modifying its elements?

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

Let's say I want to write a value in a int[], but I don't yet know what will be the length of that array.

Currently, I just run whatever algorithm I'm using once to get the length of the array, then I instanciate the array and finally run the same algorithm modifying the elements of the array.

Here's a code example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
{
    if (i == condition)
    {
        length++;
    }
}

array = new int[length];

for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
{
    if (i == condition)
    {
        array[i] = whatever;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use List<int> class instead of array. When you fill the list you can convert it into array by calling .ToArray() method.

Comment: Or use Linq and do `array = input.Where((value , index) => index == condition).Select(value => whatever).ToArray();` and don't have a loop at all ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use lists

`List<string> list = new List<string>();`

When adding elements just do:

`list.Add("Hello, world!");`

You do not need to specify length for a list and you can add as many elements as you like

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/c-sharp-list/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-6.0

Comment: Thank you so much! I had tried to use lists in the past but i thought arrays were going to do the job. Apparently I'm going to have to learn to use them both

Comment: Also, you can always use list.ToArray() if you needed to convert to array somewhere.